# What is a ring network with edges that cross the center point called?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

[image: ring topology example]

A is a ring of 8 nodes evenly spaced on a circle. Each node is connected to the next node in the ring and the node `(n+3) % 8`. Note that none of the edges pass through the center point of the circle.

B is a ring of 8 nodes evenly spaced on a circle. Each node is connected to the next node in the ring and the node `(n+4) % 8`. Note that each edge not on the outer ring passes through the center of the circle.

C is a ring of 10 evenly spaced nodes where the calculation of non-ring edges is (n+5) % 10.

For any ring with an even number of nodes it appears that if you connect a node with a next node given by `(n+(number of nodes / 2)) % number of nodes` you end up with a graph where the non-ring edges pass through the center of the circle.

What is this property called?

Note: I'm a total novice so apologies if this is easy to search for given elementary terminology.

Comment: I don't know about terminology, but it follows by noting $k+n \mod 2n$ corresponds to the node on the symmetric side. What is the definition of your property, and considering which objects?

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for a concise description of the graphs of this type. To make up name, 'ring symmetric' or 'even ring symmetric'. If anything like that exists it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are special cases of **circulant graphs** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_graph); [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html)).  Specifically, they are circulant graphs with offset list $\{1, \lfloor n/2 \rfloor\}$ (depending on your choice of notation and nomenclature).

Moreover, B and C are examples of **wheel graphs** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph)).  I don't know of a special name for A-like graphs.

Comment: The C-type graph is also a $H_{3,n}$ [Harary graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HararyGraph.html).